# How many nontrivial solutions of $-\Delta u+\sin u=0$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

When I investigate the attractor of Sine-Gordon equation, a question puzzled me, that is the number of solution of equilibrium of Sine-Gordon equation:

What is the solution of $$-\Delta u+\sin u=0,x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}.$$ We know that $u(x)=k\pi,k\in\mathbb{Z}$ are constant solutions, does there exist nontrivial solutions?

In dimension $1$, we know that $u(x)=4\arctan(e^{x})$ is a nontrivial solution. When $n\geq2$, what is the nontrivial solution? If nontrivial solution exist, finite many or infinite many? Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Some quick observations: given that $u_0(t) = 4 \arctan (e^t)$ solve the PDE in 1D, $u(x)=u_0(e\cdot x)$ solve the PDE in $n$ dimensions for any $e\in \partial B_1$. Also, adding $2\pi k$ to any non-trivial solution gives a new non-trivial solution for any $k \in \mathbb Z$

Comment: Have you tried looking for radial solutions?

Comment: A ha, thanks! I really not realized that the radial solutions, and I want to know if there exist some nontrivial solutions like $4\arctan(e^{x})$.